# C++ Error C3646, C2059, and C2238 Visual Studio 2015 (Community)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I have been trying for some time (in vain) to track down the cause of the following errors all thrown at the declaration of 'checkCollision()' in "PolygonGameObject.h" when I try to compile as a static library:

```
Error   C3646   'checkCollision': unknown override specifier    
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

In an attempt to track down the error, I have renamed the function, removed all function parameters, removed all content from the offending function (except a return statement returning an object created by the default constructor of the desired return type). For brevity, I have removed all content from the original program while still causing the same errors in an attempt to find the cause of the errors.
I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community running on Windows 7. I am compiling the source files as a static library. Below are the stripped down source files with which I have produced the error:

CollisionData.h

```
#ifndef COLLISIONDATA_H
#define COLLISIONDATA_H

#include "Vec2D.h"
#include "PolygonGameObject.h"
#include <list>

struct CollisionData
{
  double penetrationDepth;
  Vec2D collisionNormal;
  std::list<std::size_t> involvedIndicesA;
  std::list<std::size_t> involvedIndicesB;



  CollisionData();
  CollisionData(double penetrationDepth, Vec2D collisionNormal, std::list<std::size_t> involvedIndicesA, std::list<std::size_t> involvedIndicesB);
  ~CollisionData();
  static CollisionData noCollision();

};

#endif
```

CollisionData.cpp

```
#include "CollisionData.h"


using namespace std;
CollisionData::CollisionData()
{
}

CollisionData::CollisionData(double penetrationDepth, Vec2D collisionNormal,
  list<size_t> involvedIndicesA, list<size_t> involvedIndicesB):
  penetrationDepth(penetrationDepth), collisionNormal(collisionNormal),
  involvedIndicesA(involvedIndicesA), involvedIndicesB(involvedIndicesB)
{
}


CollisionData::~CollisionData()
{
}

CollisionData CollisionData::noCollision()
{
  return CollisionData(-1, Vec2D(0,0), list<size_t>(), list<size_t>());
}
```

PolygonGameObject.h

```
#ifndef POLYGONGAMEOBJECT_H
#define POLYGONGAMEOBJECT_H

#include "CollisionData.h"



class PolygonGameObject
{
protected:
  double restitution;
  double density;
  double invMass;

public:
  PolygonGameObject();
  virtual ~PolygonGameObject();
  static CollisionData checkCollision();
};
#endif
```

PolygonGameObject.cpp

```
#include "PolygonGameObject.h"
#include "CollisionData.h"
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>


PolygonGameObject::PolygonGameObject()
{
}

PolygonGameObject::~PolygonGameObject()
{
}

CollisionData PolygonGameObject::checkCollision()
{
  return CollisionData();
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Please specify which line generates the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a circular include, where PolygonGameObject.h contains `#include "CollisionData.h"` and vice versa. That is not possible.

I can't see that any `PolygonGameObject` is used in CollisionData.h, so you could just remove the unneeded include from that header.